# README.md same line alignment

Tags: html, readme

I'm currently trying to make a README.md file for github. [image: Here's what i have at the moment]

But I want them to be on the same line.
Here's the code so far:

```
<h2 align="center">Ciao</h2>
<p align="right">
    <a href=""><strong>English Version »</strong></a>
</p>
```

I tried with a div, but didn't do the work

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using flexbox:

```html
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between; align-items: center;">
   <h2>Ciao</h2>
   <a href=""><strong>English Version »</strong></a>
</div>
```

I also removed the paragraph in order to `a` tag work properly.

Comment: That didn't work as expected https://imgur.com/a/Iasno8Q

Comment: Do you use some kind of online editor? If so I will try it. @mitra02

Comment: I just tried the code on github, copy and paste on a README.md file